# undefined collection name Meteor with React

Tags: meteor, reactjs

This Meteor React client code produces browser console error:

> ReferenceError: CarsCol is not defined

Any idea why? Thanks

```
//cars.jsx

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { composeWithTracker } from 'react-komposer';
import { ListItems } from '../containers/myList.jsx';

const composer = (props, onData) => {
  const sub = Meteor.subscribe('carsCol');
  if (sub.ready()) {
     const cars = CarsCol.find().fetch();  //<------- error line
    onData(null, {cars});
   }
};

const Container = composeWithTracker(composer) (ListItems);
ReactDOM.render(<Container />, document.getElementById('react-root'));


//publications.js

const CarsCol = new Mongo.Collection('carsCol');
Meteor.publish('carsCol', function(){
  return CarsCol.find();
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've defined the collection on the server only, you want to define the collection in both places.

What I would do is define your collection in a separate file and import that.

/api/collections/CarsCol

```
const CarsCol = new Mongo.Collection('carsCol');
```

Then in cars.jsx

```
import CarsCol from '../api/collections/CarsCol'
```